# How to place 2 items in a flex row 1 left justified and 1 right justified

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 2 graphic images that I want placed into a flex row.  I want the first item to left justified and the second item to be right justified.  This is the code I am running:

```
 <div class="flex-container">     
    <div class="flex-item-left">         
       <img src="images1.png">     
    </div>     
    <div class="flex-item">         
       <img src="images2.png">     
    </div>
 </div>
```

And this is the .css that I have:

```
 .flex-container {   
    display: flex;   
    align-items: center;   
    justify-content: center; 
  }
  .flex-item {  
   }
  .flex-item-left {   
     justify-items: flex-start;
   }
```

It was my understanding that `justify-items: flex-start` would pull the item with this class to the beginning of the flex container.  In my case, this should pull image1.png to the left margin.  However, both images get placed in the center of the flex box.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: place two containers that are full-column-width and adjust their contents appropriately. Or try CSS-Grid

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code and found out that you don't need to have the ".flex-item-left" class. Go into your ".flex-container" class and change the "justify-content: center" to "justify-content: space-between".

This is what your CSS should look like:

```
 .flex-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;  
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `justify-content: space-between;` on the `flex` parent.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item-left">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200/000/fff">
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use `margin-right: auto;` on `:first-child` with `flex` on the parent which will do the same thing. This will become useful when you start building more complex flex layouts.

W/ `margin-right: auto;` on `first-child`.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-item:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200/000/fff">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can simplify your layout quite a bit. You don't really need the `.flex-item-left` and `.flex-item` wrapping elements. You can simply use `justify-content: space-between` on the `.flex-container` div and you are good to go.

Some more explanation on `justify-items`:
The `justify-items` attribute is meant to be set on the wrapping container and has the effect that all elements within that container get `justify-self: center`.